# Regular expression to find substring in text

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file contains some strings I want to extract with Java regex,
Those strings are in format of:

`$numbers,numbers,numbers....,numbers##`

(start with `$`, followed by groups of numbers plus `,`, and end with `##`)
Here is my pattern.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("$*##");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find())
    {

    }
```

It turns out that nothing match my pattern
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to start for you.

Comment: `$` is special in regex (you probably need to escape it), `*` means that **part before it** can appear zero or more times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\$\\d+(,\\d+)*##$");
```

Thanks to @Pshemo for his valuable inputs to reach the solution.

Comment: Did you test it? I have a feeling that you can have problems with `$` and greediness of `*`.

Comment: `.*` is the *worst* thing you can do, if you know the delimeters on both sides!

Comment: @dognose i know that but that is what OP asked for

Comment: @Sanjeev No, it isn't. He clearly stated, that there should only be digits and/or a `,` between the tags. `.*` will match ANYTHING - even the `##` itself, if there is another one behind...

Comment: @Pshemo I am not sure why it is not working for you. kindly re-check

Comment: I did http://ideone.com/VIbXwy. `"$$bar## foo $$123##"` is not correct result. Inly `$$123##` should be returned.

Comment: @Pshemo got your point. Sorry for all this. Please see updated answer

Comment: Now it looks better, although it could cause [catastrophic-backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) for data like `"$$1123123123123123123123,123,132,,,123,,,123,,,1,23,##"`. Instead of `(\\d+,?)+` consider using `\\d+(,\\d+)*` or `(\\d+,)*\\d+`

Comment: @Sanjeev There is no need for another answer, one is fine especially that you are close to correct solution. Feel free to update your answer or if you want I can do it for you.